# Employee serial Number based on hiring date

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Please assist amending the code below. what I want to do is creating unique serial number for each employee based on their hiring date eg. on was hired on 1/13/2016 the serial number comes with the last two digital number of (year,month,day+00) that means (16011300) for the one who hired in the same day and (year,month,day+01) that means (16011301)for the second one who hired in the same day. and do the same thing for those hired on different days. see pic below first what the code do but the second what I want it to be. thanks in advance for assistance
the used code:

```
  Dim myDate As Date, i As Long, dayPart As String
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  For i = 2 To Rows.Count
  If Cells(i, 5).Value > 1 And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5).Value) Then
     myDate = Cells(i, 5)
     dayPart = Format(Year(myDate), "00") - 2000 & _
               Format(Month(myDate), "00") & _
               Format(Day(myDate), "00") & 1
     Cells(i, 2) = dayPart
  End If
  Next i
  Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1):

If your list stays sorted by Hiring Date you can just put the following formula in B2 and draw it down:

=IF(E2=E1,B1+1,VALUE(TEXT(E2,"YYMMDD")&"00"))

EDIT:

In case of unsorted lists use the following formula in B2 and draw it down:

=TEXT(E2,"YYMMDD")&TEXT(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E2),"00")

or (if you want it as a number instead of text):

=VALUE(TEXT(E2,"YYMMDD")&TEXT(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,E2),"00"))

Comment: Thanks Jochen, you are great guy. but one more question if you do not mind, how about if the two similar dates not in order. eg. ("E2")=1/1/2016 and the below one is 3/3/2016 and the third below cell is 1/1/2016. how can I do here. sorry for troubling you with me questions.

Comment: No problem. I edited my solution to support unsorted lists.

Comment: many thanks Jochen, I really cannot but to thank you and hope you all the best. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply a format mask (see [Number Format Codes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68)) that included both date/time characters as well as a regular integer character, but if you convert the integer to the number of hours then your **Emp no** can be created in one shot.

```
Dim i As Long, seq As Long, dayPart As String

With Worksheets("employees")
    For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        seq = Application.CountIf(.Columns(5).Resize(i - 1, 1), .Cells(i, "E").Value)
        dayPart = Format(.Cells(i, "E").Value2 + TimeSerial(seq, 0, 0), _
                            "yymmddhh")
        .Cells(i, "B") = dayPart
    Next i
End With
```

After collecting the number of previous matching dates with a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34), the returned integer is converted to hours with [TimeSerial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and added to the **hiring date**. A format mask of `yymmddhh` generated the entire **Emp no**.

Granted, this is limited to 24 new employee hires per day.

[image: emp_no_frequency]

Comment: As usual, you are one of the best who gives a great short and to the point  answers in VBA. many thanks Jeeped, Appreciate it.